# LostFocus handling issue

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox, lostfocus

I want to handle `LostFocus` event of `TextBox` to perform some actions. But I'm also wouldn't want to perform that actions if `TextBox` lost it focus because special `Button` (which opens `OpenFileDialog`) was clicked or `Key.Enter` was catched. When `Key.Enter` was pressed, first of all `KeyDown` event is raised. Here my event handler of `KeyDown`:

```
public void TextBox_KeyDown(object sender, System.Windows.Input.KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e != null && sender != null)
        if (e.Key == System.Windows.Input.Key.Enter && !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(((TextBox)sender).Text))
        {
            e.Handled = true;
            isEnterClicked = true;
            ((System.Windows.Controls.TextBox)sender).Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Collapsed;
        }
}
```

After Key.Enter was pressed, TextBox.Visibility is changed, and this operator will raise LostFocus event.

```
public void TextBox_LostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        if (!isEnterClicked)
        {
            DependencyObject dob = (DependencyObject)sender;
            while ( !(dob is ItemsControl))
            {
                dob = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(dob);
            }
            dynamic myCmd = dob.GetValue(Control.DataContextProperty);
            myCmd.SomeCommand.Execute(((TextBox)sender).GetValue(Control.DataContextProperty));
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        isEnterClicked = false;
    }
}
```

`LostFocus` handler firstly watch whether `isEnterPressed` equals to false, its mean, `TextBox` lost it focus not because enter was pressed. `SomeCommand` will delete some item which was bind to `TextBox`, and it will disappear.

**Q:** So, how to do the same with `Button.Click` event?

First of all, **BEFORE** `Button` clicked, `TextBox` lost it focus. The same way is not acceptable. `Button.Focusable="False"`, creating new `ControlTemplate` or handling `Timer.Elapsed` event do not satisfy my requirements.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood problem correctly, try to check if button is focused, if so dont perform actions in textbox lostfocus event. If Iam correct button should be focused before textbox lostfocus event raised.

```
if (!isEnterClicked && !button.Focused)
{
    //do stuff
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work. `LostFocus` raises earlier, than `Button.IsFocused` will set to `true`.

Comment: i tied in winforms and i thought that in wpf it could work different :/